# Как сложить все числа выведенные в textBox?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем мне нужно сложить первую сумму со второй.
Чтобы был как бы "чек общей суммы" за все выбранные элементы из `comboBox`. Как определяю сумму:
выбираю из `comboBox` нужную мне комплектующую, затем ввожу количество в `textBox` и затем жму посчитать, сумма выводится в отдельный `textBox` после этого, в этот же `textBox` мне нужно посчитать сумму всех выбранных товаров таким образом чтобы было допустим - выбрал как на скрине и снизу было написано - Итог общей суммы = 33000. Как мне это реализовать? У меня есть условие, в котором описано если выбран тот или иной элемент из `comboBox` то этой переменной присваиваю значение (цену). Затем я ввожу количество эта переменная 2я закреплена за `textBox` в который я ввожу количество, и третья это сумма которая получится если количество будет выбрано больше 1го. В конце я вывожу таким образом

```
textBox5->Text += comboBox1->Items[comboBox1->SelectedIndex] + "\r\n" + a + " x " + b + " = " + c + "\r\n";
```

Как сделать так чтобы сумма "процессора" сложилась с суммой "Блока питания" и вывела итог?

Comment: `c` - вот ваши значения, их складывайте.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, я не особо понимаю как их складывать. Пытался, выводило лишь по новой ту же сумму, что и у каждого товара.